# (Windows 10) Recently PC running all tasks slowly and having bad performance

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, overclocking, framerate

Heyy forum!
So I have this pretty high-end PC I've had since 2015 and only recently it seems to be giving up.

Whenever I try to do any tasks that requires some more power, my PC seems to struggle and everything slows way down. Because of this I can barely do two tasks at the same time and I can't play any games I was able to before.

My specs are:

**Windows 10 Home x64**

**Motherboard: MSI B150M Night Elf**

**Processor: Intel Core I7-6700 (Overclocked)**

**Graphics Card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 (Overclocked)**

**RAM: 16 GBs**

**Storage:**

**Kingston 120 GBs SSD (SV300S37A120G)**

**SeaGate 465 GBs HDD (ST500LT012-1DG142)**

**Western Digital 1 TB HDD (WDC WD10EZEX-60ZF5A0)**

Task manager shows no high usage on anything, CPU, Memory, Disk, GPU is all below 20% unless I'm running a game. But I do see a random 100% spike in the GPU 3D Performance Window.

Cleaned up the dust inside and changed the thermal paste, still the same.
I have freshly reinstalled from a USB and completely cleaned and optimized the drives.
Stress tested the CPU, GPU, Memory and HDDs by their respective software, all gave me no problems detected. Everything passed.

I really don't know where the problem lies, since everything seems to be okay. Thought it might be a failing HDD but tests turned out fine, thought it might be Processor or Memory but again, tests turned out fine.

The only thing I'm not sure about is when I reinstalled, it showed me 2 other drives, which were using a small amount of space, one was for Windows Backup I think, I don't remember what the other one was about.

Could some malware have crawled into those backup storage spaces and is tearing me apart, *Lisa*?
Or could it be this Creator Update for Windows 10 that everyone is saying is bad?

I will show my HWMonitor stuff too:
[HWMonitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAUn3.jpg)

Appreciate all the help you can give! :)

Comment: it can be for various reasons. without teamviewer to your PC. I cannot give specific answers. However, to simplify your life, how about reinstall winows 10 again ?

Comment: I have reinstalled twice already, but will try again later on I guess. This time I will format all storage partitions, even those small ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use High Performance power plan.

Update system to the latest version

Scan virus and malware in safe mode

Check if there is any AV or security software are scanning in background

Try Microsoft Performance Toolkit

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/

Reset system, keep my files.